# Running Facebook PHP Callback with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've been stuck on an experimental project for a while and I was wondering if anyone might be able to take a look and see what I'm doing wrong and what I should be doing. Apologies in advance for the lengthy message!

I have a main page and a separate PHP page - **sign_fb.php** - that handles a Facebook login. In short, a user clicks a button, a prompt (SweetAlert) asks if they want to continue, and if the user clicks yes/OK, then the Facebook page runs.

I'm able to accomplish the overall goal using two PHP files (based on the Facebook documentation) and just using `header` to switch back to the main page and display a message, but that seems a little messy. I've been trying to use Javascript/jQuery to handle an AJAX request to have the whole process be more dynamic but still use the Facebook PHP SDK, and I'm running into a bit of a dead end. Ultimately, I'd like to basically run the login URL that Facebook provides (`$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();`, etc.) when the user clicks "OK" on the first prompt and have the second prompt be the result as returned by the callback PHP script (e.g. OK or not OK).

Here's the code (I'm still in the process of learning JS!):

```
function runFacebook() {
    swal({
        title: "Login with Facebook?",
        text: "Click OK to log in with Facebook.",
        type: "info",
        showCancelButton: true,
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    }), $.ajax({
            url: 'sign_fb.php',
            type: "GET",
            data: user,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                console.log(user);
            }
        });
};
```

**sign_fb.php** is pretty much what's on the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login), e.g. "fb-callback.php", and it contains the app ID, secret, etc. ... after I get the access token I'm just running:

```
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
echo $user;
```

What I'm running into is I'm not exactly sure what parameters to put in the `$.ajax` function, specifically "data". Ideally, if the script runs, then the "success" function should run (just another SweetAlert message), and if there's an error on the PHP end (e.g. if an account exists), then either PHP would return that as a variable or there'd be a catchall error popup for that.

In this example I'm just trying to grab the `$user` element as a JSON element and then print it in the console, but I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined" - probably because there's no "user" variable in Javascript, as I'm not sure. In sign_fb.php, I'm trying to just return the JSON $user element using `echo $user;`, but JS is looking for something else, and I'm not sure what to put (I'm not sure where to "return" a value from the PHP file, hence the echo).

Is there a way to mix up the PHP SDK and JS like this for an AJAX call, or is it preferable to stick with the JS SDK? (I've avoided using the JS SDK for no reason other than I'm still pretty much a newbie at JS.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `data:user` is not `console.log(user);` you need to do it like this `data: parametersYouArePassing` via php script needs to be here then on success you need to pass data to the function as an argument, it better be `function(data)`, Note that data:user is not the same as `function(data)`

Comment: First data (`data:user`) is for the data that you provide in GET to the sign_fb.php and `function(data)` is the data you receive after the execution of sign_fb.php

Comment: Where/how are you calling the FB login dialog?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...I think what's ultimately tripping me up is I have the FB login link and the callback PHP and I'm trying to set them up together. In my site's header I use the login helper (`$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();` and `$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($siteUrl.'/sign_fb.php', $permissions);`, but I'm not sure how to link up the SweetAlert dialog so that when OK is clicked it goes through Facebook. Would this require the JS SDK rather than PHP?